# How to extract all user-defined static members of a class to an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Code here:

```js
class Base {
  static get name() {
    return 'teresa teng';
  }
  static hello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  static getById() {
    console.log('getById');
  }
}

const staticMembers = extractStaticMembers(Child);
```

The goal is to get all user-defined static members(except `prototype`, `length` props) from the `Child` class, including those inherited from the `Base` class. And put these static members in an object. How to implements the `extractStaticMembers` function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Object.values(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Child)).filter(({writable}) => writable).map(({value}) => value)` would be a start.

Comment: ...plus something for getters and setters.